# greek alphabet in mtext R

Tags: r

I have the next part of my code

```
    mtext(expression("log([OIII]5007/Hb)"), side = 2,cex = 0.8, line = 1.2)
```

That "b" in my expression should be a beta, I've tried using \beta  and others but it doesn't work, how can I change that b for beta?

Comment: Try using `bquote()` instead

Comment: You can also use unicode symbols in R plots. To print a beta, you can use `"\u03b2"` in your string. So in your case, try `"log([OIII]5007/H\u03b2)"`. I've found that using unicode works better for me than plotmath commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one,

```
mtext(expression(paste("log([OIII]5007/H ",beta)), side = 2,cex = 0.8, line = 1.2)
```